# How can I make a shorter binary rule in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy

Here is a code I experimented with recently:

```hs
let br = [0]:[n:(concat $ take n br) | n <- [1..]] in concat br
```

This code produces the [binary rule](https://oeis.org/A007814) `0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 ...`

Here is the idea of how it works:

- create a list starting with [0]
- each step, concatenate all the current elements in the list, put the next number at the begining and add at the end.

```
[[0] ...]
[[0], [1, 0] ...]
[[0], [1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0]...]
[[0], [1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0] ...]
...
```

My question now is: is there a shorter/smarter one-liner to get this infinite lazy binary-rule ?

### Edit:

I found another way to do the same thing:

```hs
let f n = if n==0 then [0] else n:([0..n-1] >>= f) in [0..]>>= f
```

The extra question would be: wich one of the 2 version is more readable for an haskell programmer, and why ?

Comment: Re Edit 2: The python version should be `yield 0 \n for b...: yield b+1 \n yield 0`

Comment: Re Edit 2: The haskell version: I confirm that it hangs, and I'm trying to figure out why. This works: `import Data.List (intersperse) \n binaryRule = 0 : intersperse 0 ((+1) <$> binaryRule)`

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem, but I think we've pissed off the mods enough with _troubleshooting_ on _Code Review_, and I want my fake internet points in the right place anyway :) . Open a thread on Stack Overflow and share the link here!

Comment: To be clear chameleon questions - questions where what is being asked changes over time - are not allowed on Code Review. If you'd like advice on _working_ code (which your Edit 2 is not) you can ask a follow-up question. Alternately you could take @ShapeOfMatter up on the offer to ask on Stack Overflow. Please do not undo my rollback or 'the mods' _may_ become pissed off ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little out of practice with haskell, but I'm quite fond of it. I want to address your "extra" question first.

> wich one of the 2 version is more readable for an haskell programmer, and why ? [sic]

Haskell programmers aren't a special magic kind of people. They tend to take the benefits of brevity more seriously than folks in love with python, but I think they'll still agree that golfed code is not readable/smarter/better. The basic rule of good (code) writing applies: *Write what you mean*.

> - create a list starting with [0]
> - each step, concatenate all the current elements in the list, put the next number at the beginning and add at the end.

Neither of your proposed solutions is *obviously* doing that, although it only takes a minute to see that your first solution *is* doing that.

[Noughtmare's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/261242/200133) suggestion is based on a different construction of the OEIS sequence, although the OEIS presents this as an *invariant*, not a construction, so the reader still needs to think the matter through (a little).

Give-or-take efficiency, write code that *obviously* does what you're saying it does. Unfortunately, the OEIS entry doesn't describe the sequence in terms that translate directly to a lazy infinite list declaration, so you need to provide some documentation of your own.

```hs
-- https://oeis.org/A007814
rulerSequence :: [Integer]
rulerSequence = concat halfs
  where seed = [0, 1]
        -- The sequence is built by concatenating with itself
        -- and incrementing the last index. `nextHalf` builds
        -- the right-hand-side of each such concatenation.
        nextHalf priorHalfs = let priors = concat priorHalfs
                              in (init priors) ++ [(last priors) + 1]
        halfs = seed:[nextHalf (take iteration halfs) | iteration <- [1..]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an `interleave` helper:

```hs
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs

binaryRule :: [Integer]
binaryRule = interleave [0,0..] (map (+ 1) binaryRule)
```

Or golfed: `let(a:b)#c=a:c#b;a=[0,0..]#map(+1)a in a`